# print function is not working fine with the script code

Tags: javascript, printing

`

.styled-button-2 {

-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0976562) 0px 1px 0px 0px;

background-color: #EEE;

border: 1px solid #999;

color: #666;

font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif;

font-size: 11px;

font-weight: bold;

padding: 2px 6px;

height: 28px;

}

//Controls which Web Part or zone to print

var WebPartElementID = "webpartzone1";

//Function to print Web Part

function PrintWebPart()

{
var bolWebPartFound = false;

if (document.getElementById != null)

{

//Create html to print in new window

var PrintingHTML = '\n\n';

//Take data from Head Tag

if (document.getElementsByTagName != null)

{

var prButton = document.getElementById('printButton');

```
    prButton.style.display = 'none';
```

var HeadData= document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD");

if (HeadData.length > 0)

```
PrintingHTML += HeadData[0].innerHTML;
```

}

PrintingHTML += '\n\n\n';

var WebPartData = document.getElementById(WebPartElementID);

if (WebPartData != null)

{

window.print();
}

else

{
bolWebPartFound = false;

alert ('Cannot Find Web Part');

}
}
PrintingHTML += '\n\n';

//Open new window to print

if (bolWebPartFound)

{

var PrintingWindow = window.open
("","PrintWebPart", "toolbar,width=800,height=600,scrollbars,resizable,menubar");

PrintingWindow.document.open();

PrintingWindow.document.write(PrintingHTML);

// Open Print Window

PrintingWindow.print();

}

prButton.style.display = '';

}

New window is opened while hitting the print button, but blank page with script error alone showing

Comment: So what error or output are you getting??

Comment: New window is opened while hitting the print button, but blank page with script error alone showing